# HiveQL to query Aerospike

Tags: hive, aerospike

Hi Aerospike Community,

I'm able to read aerospike set using spark-sql and I'm looking a similar way to read from Hive QL (or through storage handler). Can you please let me know how to do it?

**Spark-sql Working:**

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE aero USING com.aerospike.spark.sql OPTIONS (
 "aerospike.seedhost"="10.180.16.255", "aerospike.port"="3000",
 "aerospike.namespace"="test", "aerospike.set"="one_million");

 SELECT column1, column2, intcolumn1 FROM aero;
```

**HiveQL:**

> ??

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aerospike has a connector for spark but not for Hive yet. So, you cannot have a simple query interface to Aerospike from Hive till a connector is built.